Delay or Blank Screen When Switching from Image to Video onmouseenter in next js
I'm making a website where when you hover over an image, it should switch to a video. But sometimes, there's a delay or the screen briefly goes blank before the video starts playing.
I've optimized the video files to reduce their size to kilobytes (KBs). The video playback is smooth once it starts, and I've used preload="auto" for the video element.
When hovering over the image, the smaller video should replace the image seamlessly without any delays or blank screens. It should start playing immediately.
Here's my code:
const AiToolsData = (props) => {

  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  return (
    <GridItem
      colSpan={{
        sm: props.uniqueKey === 0 ? 2 : 1,
      }}
      maxH={"425px"}
      pos={"relative"}
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
    >
      {isHovered ? (
        <video
          src={props.videoSrc}
          width={100}
          height={100}
          className="tools-cards"
          autoPlay
          loop
          muted
          playsInline
          preload="auto"
        />
      ) : (
        <Image
          src={props.imgSrc}
          width={100}
          height={100}
          className="tools-cards"
          loading="eager"
          priority={true}
          alt="Apple"
        />
      )}
    </GridItem>
  );
};


I think the problem is that you are switching them based on re-render per state change, when the correct approach would be hide or not it.
Although it would be good for this delay, it may cause a delay on page loading. So that it'd be good to consider what's the strategy you are going to use to serve this video (streaming instead of the entire video).
